# Tableau---Getting count from 2 different data sources and combining into one total

Tags: count, tableau-api, aggregation

I am a tableau newbie and am trying to see if this is possible or not.  I have 2 separate data sources where the same employees are listed, one is for closed cases and the other is for open cases.  These data sources have some of the same columns, but for the most part they are different.

Is it possible to aggregate the case count for each employee on the closed and open data sources into a single column? For instance, if an employee has 50 closed cases and 23 open cases, I want it to show 73 for them.

I attempted to play around with the joins/unions but these didn't work properly and duplicated the data most times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a great chance to leverage blends.

I have created a workbook with the Sample Superstore Excel dataset. This dataset has three sheets. I'll use the Orders and Returns sheets to demonstrate how we can calculate the net orders using blends.

The dataset I'm using can be found [here](https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-1236).

Start by connecting to both the Orders and Returns separately. Once done with this step you should see the two data sources at the top of your data pane.

In this example, I'll calculate the Net Returns by Category. In your case, you're after the Total Cases by Employee, so just imagine Employee in place of Category.

Next, drag Category from the Orders data source onto the view, then select the Orders data source and click the chain icon to blend on Order ID.

> You will need a common column between the two tables in order to blend.

[image]

Once blended I'll go back to the primary data source (indicated by the blue check mark) and create the Net Orders calculation.

[image]

This calculation uses the dot notation - similar to what you might see in SQL - to reference our other table.

To double check that our calculation is working properly, we can drag the components of this calculation onto the view and do the math.

[image]

Of course, once you are satisfied you can remove all but your blended calculation.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for...took me a little while to get used to how things work in tableau versus Excel but I am really impressed with how easy things are once you get the hang of it compared to Excel where some things are not possible outside Power Pivot

Comment: Oh that's great to hear @MattE. Yeah, Tableau operates like SQL under that hood, but the interface is obviously different which can be very confusing after first. Do let me know if you have any other questions :)

Comment: One small issue I had a question on...I am using the closed case employee names and linking with the open case employee names. However, there are cases when an employee is in the open case but not in the closed cases and it doesn't show up, assuming because it's only taking the closed case names.  Is there a way to ensure that ALL names from both open and closed cases are shown with their case counts?

Comment: You're right that you'll only see employees from the primary dataset and their associated employees from the secondary dataset. If there are employees in the secondary dataset that aren't in the primary, they won't show up. At this point, I would restructure these two tables into a single Union with a column for the employee, open/closed state and case count. That will make your life much easier! And this is common in Tableau to do you data munging outside the tool to make the visualizations work smoothly. Hope that helps.

Comment: You're right that you'll only see employees from the primary dataset and their associated employees from the secondary dataset. If there are employees in the secondary dataset that aren't in the primary, they won't show up. At this point, I would restructure these two tables into a single Union with a column for the employee, open/closed state and case count. That will make your life much easier! And this is common in Tableau to do you data munging outside the tool to make the visualizations work smoothly. Hope that helps.

Comment: OK thanks!  I have Tableau Prep, would this be a good use case for this?

Comment: Yep, a perfect use case for prep! Good thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Blending isn't ideal in most cases but you could try it. Bring in each data source separately and "join" them within your workbook pane on Employee or hopefully an Employee_id. Click the little chain once you have them both loaded and you are on a worksheet tab. Then you could sum the counts by employee. Blending sometimes presents some issues with calculated fields across the two data sources but this is what I would try first.